# Need all members outlook calender events of my groups using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: asp.net, api, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

Can anyone know how can I retrieve My group's all members outlook calendar events using Microsoft Graph API? Consider me as admin of that group.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you could get all members in your groups.

Please refer to this link:

[Microsoft Graph API Get ALL members from a supplied group](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/040f7beb-917b-47a7-a69d-1df6fafb5f70/microsoft-graph-api-get-all-members-from-a-supplied-group?forum=WindowsAzureAD)

Then you could get calendar events on the member’s calendar.

[List Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0)